# numpy.core._exceptiond._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate using matplotlib.imshow

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, memory

I am currently trying to plot a 3D dataset with a length of (1600,1600,1600) in the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

# Load the 3D data file
data = np.genfromtxt("Ta_parameterspace_2mm.txt", skip_header=14, delimiter="\t", dtype = float)
print(data)
reflect = data[:,0]
emiss = data[:,1]
temp = data[:,2]
tempdiff = data[:,4]

# Create a meshgrid for the x, y, and z coordinates
x1, y1, z1 = np.meshgrid(reflect, emiss, temp)
# Plot the data using imshow
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.imshow(data, extent=[x1.min(), x1.max(), y1.min(), y1.max()], origin='lower', cmap='viridis')
plt.show()
```

However, if I run the code, I get the following error:

```
    x1, y1, z1 = np.meshgrid(reflect, emiss, temp)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in meshgrid
  File "C:\Users\t.smart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 5045, in meshgrid
    output = [x.copy() for x in output]
  File "C:\Users\t.smart\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py", line 5045, in <listcomp>
    output = [x.copy() for x in output]
numpy.core._exceptions._ArrayMemoryError: Unable to allocate 30.5 GiB for an array with shape (1600, 1600, 1600) and data type float64
```

On the computer that I am running the code, I do not have admin privileges and I have 8gb of RAM.

How do I solve this error?

Comment: You're using meshgrid but you do not use the result to do something useful. Calculate your extent directly with the `data` variable.

Comment: @obchardon How would I do this?

Comment: `extent=[data[:,0].min(), data[:,0].max(), data[:,1].min(), data[:,1].max()]`